# C# не отображается график на Chart

Tags: c#, фурье

Всем привет. Написал программу, принимающее на вход wav-файл и строящий частотно-временной спектр в Chart, но не могу грамотно прописать отображение. Помогите пожалуйста!
Код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Wave files (*.wav)|*.wav";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                DrawFrequencyTimeGraph(filePath);
            }
        }

        private void DrawFrequencyTimeGraph(string filePath)
        {
            // Чтение файла wav
            WaveFile waveFile = new WaveFile(filePath);

            // Получение параметров звука
            int sampleRate = waveFile.SampleRate;
            int channels = waveFile.Channels;
            int samplesCount = waveFile.SamplesCount;

            // Размер окна для преобразования Фурье (должен быть степенью двойки)
            int windowSize = 1024;

            // Шаг в секундах для временной шкалы
            double timeStep = 1.0;

            // Количество окон для преобразования Фурье
            int windowsCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)samplesCount / (windowSize / 2));

            // Создание Chart
            Chart chart = new Chart();
            chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
            chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
            chart.Series.Add("Series1");
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Time (s)";
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Frequency (Hz)";

            // Проход по каждому окну и применение преобразования Фурье
            for (int i = 0; i < windowsCount; i++)
            {
                // Создание временного массива для текущего окна
                Complex[] window = new Complex[windowSize];

                // Заполнение временного массива данными из wav файла
                for (int j = 0; j < windowSize; j++)
                {
                    int sampleIndex = i * (windowSize / 2) + j;
                    if (sampleIndex < samplesCount)
                    {
                        double sampleValue = waveFile.GetSampleValue(sampleIndex);
                        window[j] = new Complex(sampleValue, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        window[j] = new Complex(0, 0);
                    }
                }

                // Применение преобразования Фурье
                FourierTransform.FFT(window, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);

                // Отрисовка спектра частот для текущего окна
                for (int j = 0; j < windowSize / 2; j++)
                {
                    double frequency = (double)j * sampleRate / windowSize;
                    double amplitude = window[j].Magnitude;

                    // Добавление точки на график
                    chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i * timeStep, frequency, amplitude);
                }
            }

            // Отображение графика
            chart.Show();
        }
    }

    public class WaveFile
    {
        private byte[] data;
        private int channels;
        private int sampleRate;

        public WaveFile(string filePath)
        {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                // Чтение заголовка файла
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(22, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                channels = reader.ReadInt16();
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(34, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                sampleRate = reader.ReadInt32();

                // Чтение данных
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(44, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                data = reader.ReadBytes((int)(reader.BaseStream.Length - 44));
            }
        }

        public int SampleRate
        {
            get { return sampleRate; }
        }

        public int Channels
        {
            get { return channels; }
        }

        public int SamplesCount
        {
            get { return data.Length / (channels * 2); }
        }

        public double GetSampleValue(int index)
        {
            int sampleIndex = index * channels * 2;

            // Чтение значения сэмпла в формате Little Endian
            int sampleValue = data[sampleIndex] | (data[sampleIndex + 1] << 8);

            // Преобразование значения в диапазон [-1, 1]
            return (double)sampleValue / (Math.Pow(2, 16) / 2);
        }
    }

    public class FourierTransform
    {
        public enum Direction
        {
            Forward,
            Backward
        }

        public static void FFT(Complex[] data, Direction direction)
        {
            int n = data.Length;

            if (n == 1)
                return;

            Complex[] even = new Complex[n / 2];
            Complex[] odd = new Complex[n / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
            {
                even[i] = data[2 * i];
                odd[i] = data[2 * i + 1];
            }

            FFT(even, direction);
            FFT(odd, direction);

            double angle = 2 * Math.PI / n * (direction == Direction.Forward ? 1 : -1);
            Complex w = new Complex(1, 0);
            Complex wn = new Complex(Math.Cos(angle), Math.Sin(angle));

            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
            {
                Complex temp = w * odd[i];
                data[i] = even[i] + temp;
                data[i + n / 2] = even[i] - temp;
                w *= wn;
            }
        }
    }
}
```